# C# XNA Fast pixel load

Tags: c#, xna, load, pixel

Sorry for spamming questions, but is there a fast way of loading pixels in XNA from window (not project window) ? I need to load like 100 pixels width 100 pixels height, without too much lag. (Maybe update each 10 seconds).

```
    public void UpdateMap()
    {
        for (int y = 100; y < 120; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 1500; x < 1510; x++)
            {
                uint pixel = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
                colorlist.Add(new Color((int)(pixel & 0x000000FF),
                     (int)(pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8,
                     (int)(pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. From the method name, I gather that you want to create a mini-map of sorts? Or a picture-in-picture kind of thing?

If so, this should be something you should let the GPU handle. You should look into RenderTargets:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rendertarget%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx

With them, you can render things into a texture which you can then display on the screen. This will almost certainly be the fastest and most correct way.

Maybe you could update your question with what exactly you want to accomplish so I can give you a more precise answer?